# How do I attach a timer to this?

Tags: java

I am trying to attach a 2 second (2000 milisecond) timer to this light so that it auto advances to the next color. I have been reading the java documentation and I don't understand how to use it.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class Lab4Frame extends JFrame {

    Lab4Frame(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setTitle("Lab 4 - Application #1");
        Lab4Panel p = new Lab4Panel();
        Lab4RadioButtonPanel p2 = new Lab4RadioButtonPanel(p);

        add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

            Lab4Frame frame = new Lab4Frame();
            frame.setTitle("Lab4 Application # 1");
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 600);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class Lab4RadioButtonPanel extends JPanel {
    Lab4Panel canvas;
    //Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas2 = new Lab4RadioButtonPanel();

    public Lab4RadioButtonPanel(Lab4Panel canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
        boolean red, green, yellow;
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JRadioButton jrbRed = new JRadioButton("Red", true);
        JRadioButton jrbYellow = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
        JRadioButton jrbGreen = new JRadioButton("Green");

        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(jrbRed);
        group.add(jrbYellow);
        group.add(jrbGreen);


        this.add(jrbRed);
        this.add(jrbYellow);
        this.add(jrbGreen);

        jrbRed.addActionListener(new RedListener(canvas));
        jrbYellow.addActionListener(new YellowListener(canvas));
        jrbGreen.addActionListener(new GreenListener(canvas));

    }
}


class Lab4Panel extends JPanel{


    public Lab4Panel(){}



    boolean red = true;
    boolean green = false;
    boolean yellow = false;
    int radius = 5;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;

    public void setRed(){
        yellow = false;
        green = false;
        red = true;
    }

    public void setYellow(){
        red = false;
        green = false;
        yellow = true;
    }

    public void setGreen(){
        red = false;
        yellow = false;
        green = true;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        if (x<0 || y<0) {
            x = getWidth() / 2 - radius;
            y = getHeight() / 2 - radius;
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(x - 10,y - 90, 40, 120);
        g.drawRect(x - 5,y - 90, 40, 120);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval(x,y - 80, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawOval(x,y - 40, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawOval(x,y, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);


        if(red){
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(x,y - 80, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
            repaint();
        }

        else if (yellow){
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillOval(x,y - 40, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
            repaint();
        }

        if(green){
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(x,y, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
            repaint();
        }

    }


}


class RedListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab4Panel canvas;

    RedListener(Lab4Panel canvas) {
     this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        canvas.setRed();
    }
}

class YellowListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab4Panel canvas;

    YellowListener(Lab4Panel canvas) {
     this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        canvas.setYellow();
    }
}

class GreenListener implements ActionListener{
    //private Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas;
    private Lab4Panel canvas;

    GreenListener(Lab4Panel canvas) {
     this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        canvas.setGreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: you might want to trim the code in the post to only the relevant parts

Comment: Edit: you have no timer code in your code posted above. How can we help you if you don't show us what you've tried? Again, have you read the [Swing Timer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)? Again, what specifically confuses you in it?

Comment: I was reading several sites worth of swing timer info and none of it makes sense. I was hoping someone could send me to a lower end web page.

Comment: @user512915: again, ***what*** doesn't make sense? We can't help you if you don't let us. The tutorial that I've linked to above is pretty basic and yet pretty complete. It even has sample code for you to compile and modify, and I doubt you'll find much better than that.

Comment: yes that site is what I needed thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Again, if you get stuck after going through that tutorial, then please come on back and let us know what specific you don't understand and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 class Lab4Panel extends JPanel{ 

 public Lab4Panel(){

 Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new TimerListener());
 timer.start();

 }
```

Comment: This response, by original author, gives no indication on how it solves his problem.  There's not enough code provided to demonstrate how it fits in with the original code snippets.  It's an out-of-context response to a question that originally elicited a few queries for meaningful information.